# Optimizing a Project-Euler question (#8) more

Tags: c++, optimization, numbers

The problem is solved. [(Project-Euler #8)](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8)

But I was wondering - Can we optimize it even more?

Problem -
Given a text array of numbers (lets say DATA).
Find 13 adjacent digits, whose product is the largest possible in DATA.

What I did -
[Main logic]

```
//We could process through each digit 
//"Product" it till 13 numbers - p *= digit
//Check for Larger than previous - keep this, drop that`
```

[First Optimization - Chunking]

```
// 0 zeros are such party poopers, we will avoid them.
// the digits between 0 should have some status clearance. (0XXXXX0) >= 13
//Lets call each of rest a "chunk"`
```

**The** Problem -
after this optimization, there are still ~263 chunks.
*I can smell that not all chunks are as heavy as we want.
If somehow we could drop lighter of these chunks? *

This is the code block, I came up with.

```
//Method: (DATA, window_size) ---> largest product of adjacent digits  
data func(char textnum[], int n)
{
    //Sub-method: DATA[char] ---> DATA[int]
    int bignum[1000];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
    {
        bignum[i] = int( textnum[i] ) - 48;
    }

    //Chunking: In between zeros, all the (adjacent digits) < n are dropped
    //int chunk[] : holds the index to an appropriate "chunk"
    int cnt = 0, s = 0;

    std::vector<int> chunks;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
    {
        if( bignum[i] )
            cnt++;
        else cnt = 0;
        if( cnt >= n )
        {
            chunks.push_back((i + 1) - n); 
        }
    }

    //Main Logic: 
    data p = 1, x = 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++)    //Loop: (processing through chunks in DATA)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )           //Loop: (processing till the window_size)
        {
            p *= bignum[chunks.at(i) + j];      //Product of n adjacent digits
        }
        if ( p > x )                            //Largest 
            x = p;
        p = 1;
    }

    return x;
}
```

How to optimize her more?

Comment: You question is more suitable to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @273K There is no site like that. link please.

Comment: The link is right there in the comment!

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yeah, they edited it later.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a span of non-zero numbers of size N >= 13: (presented as groups of four letters each for easy reading)

```
abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrstu ...
```

In your terminology, every sub-span of size 13 would be a 'chunk'. There are N-13 such chunks (`a-m`, `b-n`, `c-o`, etc.)

Your current code recalculates the product from scratch for each chunk from the same span:

```
p_1 = a * b * ... * m;
p_2 =     b * ... * m * n;
p_3 =         ... * m * n * o;
```

In other words: `p_2 = p_1 / a * n;` and `p_3 = p_2 / b * o;`

You can do this for other chunks in the same span and come out ahead, as L1 cache accesses are cheap but not free.

Comment: I think you'd need to benchmark this pretty carefully to be sure whether it was a win. Division is considerably slower than multiplication, so you need to save a fair number of multiplications to justify a single division. I'm not saying it can't work out, but it's not immediately obvious that it usually will.

Comment: @JerryCoffin You save 12 L1 cache accesses and 12 multiplications for every iteration (after the first) with this technique. Taking the ice lake CPU from [this document of timings by Agner Fog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) as an example, 64-bit multiplication is on average 1 cycle, whereas division is 6 or 10 cycles. L1 cache accesses are widely reported to be 0.5 ns, or 2 cycles for a 4Ghz processor. Taking the widely unscientific approach of summing cycle counts, I end up at 10+1+2 cycles vs 12+26.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: it might well be faster--but it's close enough that I wouldn't trust it without pretty careful testing.

Comment: I came across this solution earlier. I appreciate this solution. @Botje Thanks.
It is an optimization anyway.
This solution however seems like a sliding window kind for products. Cool Cool.
What I put forth as the challenge is this!
Given n = 13 +x chunk, I would have x chunks of 13 size.
I know the chunks which are lighter (groups of smaller digits) would surely produce a smaller product.
If we could skip those altogether. 
Just how we would visually process. (i know thats not how processor works).

Comment: @Botje One more thing, how did you edit my code to make it streamlined.
Looks so much pleasing. I am tad bit new hereeeee

Comment: I used triple backticks to make them code segments. As for your other question: no, there is no easy way to rule our "light" chunks.